# Bootstrap panel template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

H guys i am new to bootstrap and trying to create a pannel template, however i am so bad at it that i am not really getting anywhere, could someone please explain to me how to get the rest of it, i am close but just trying to crate the rest right now.

[image: This is what i am trying to create. I have done some of it but i just cant seem to get the rest of it right. Any help on this topic would be great. Thanks]

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFKV/133/)

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel Title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Item 01</div>
                        <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you guys for the help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, it looks like you want to create a list next to your internal panel.

Easy. Just create another `div` with the grid column values set.

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Item 01</div>
            <div class="panel-body"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Setting the column values so the totals equal 12 -->
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
          <h4>
          List Title
          </h4>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Item One</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Item Two</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1wu4ojm/4/)

Comment: That is perfect, can i just ask how u can add a button under the image box? like just a simple button

Comment: And sorry a box below the button box, would that be a new div?

Comment: @Nevershow2016 - I've updated the jsfiddle to include a new box below the div. I think this demonstrates how the bootstrap grid system works. Just play - I'm sure you can figure it out from here.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , its great xx

Comment: Ah also that div This is a big panel in another grid cell was suppose to be just under the other div but i think i got it x